When using biometrics in react-native, iOS Face ID prompts comes only at the second time
I use expo SecureStore to store the session token in my react-native app like this:
await SecureStore.setItemAsync(
  'session',
  JSON.stringify({
    ...JSON.parse(session),
    refreshToken,
  }),
  {
    requireAuthentication: true,
  },
);

This should bring the FaceID prompt in iOS. But it does not. If I call this twice, then it shows the FaceID prompt. Any idea why this is happening?
Minimal representation: https://github.com/THPubs/expo-secure-store-biometrics
When you delete an item, you need to trigger the storing function twice for the device to prompt for faceID.

Did you concider to try out the react-native-touch-id lib.
I'm using it for face id and its working fine. Check the belo code


import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';
import {Toast} from './Helper';

const Touchid = () => {
  const [biometryType, setBiometryType] = useState('');
  const optionalConfigObject = {
    title: 'Face App',
    imageColor: '#B69377', // Android
    imageErrorColor: '#B69377', // Android
    sensorDescription: 'Touch sensor', // Android
    sensorErrorDescription: 'Failed', // Android
    cancelText: 'Cancel', // Android
    fallbackLabel: 'Show Passcode', // iOS (if empty, then label is hidden)
    unifiedErrors: false, // use unified error messages (default false)
    passcodeFallback: true, // iOS: allows the device to fall back to using the passcode if faceid or touch is not available. This does not mean that if touchid or faceid fails the first few times, it will revert to a passcode; rather, if the former are not enrolled, then it will use the passcode.
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (true)
      TouchID.isSupported(optionalConfigObject)
        .then(biometryType => {
          console.log(biometryType);

          // Success code
          if (biometryType === 'FaceID') {
            setBiometryType('FaceID');
          } else {
            setBiometryType('TouchID');
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Failure code
          console.log('err', error);
        });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (biometryType === 'FaceID' || biometryType === 'TouchID') {
      authenticate();
    }
  }, [biometryType]);
  const authenticate = () => {
    TouchID.authenticate(
      'Face App Require TouchID for Verification ',
      optionalConfigObject,
    )
      .then(success => {
        if (success) {
          Toast('success');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} backgroundColor={'#aaaaaa'} />
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        authenticate();
      }}>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 15,
          alignSelf: 'center',
          margin: 20,
          marginTop:150,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          color: 'white',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          textAlignVertical: 'center',
          textAlign: 'center',
          borderRadius:20,
          padding:10,
        }}>
        Click here to continue
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  );
};

export default Touchid;



